# I want to make this program loop

Tags: python

I am making a super simple color guessing game and I want to make it so that you can guess multiple times without the program stopping

```
color = input("guess color please ")

if color == "red":
    print('you got it right')
else:
    print("you are wrong")
```

Answer (score 2):

```
color = ""
while color != "red":
    color = input("guess color please ")

    if color == "red":
        print('you got it right')
    else:
        print("you are wrong")
```

The trick here is the 'while' statement, that will make your program go into a loop unless it's canceled (ctrl+C) or the condition in satisfied (color == "red")

Answer (score 0):

In Python, you can use a `while` loop to repeat a section of code while a certain condition is true. In your case, you must loop when the answer isn’t `red`. (Make sure to define your variable before the loop so that it doesn’t raise a `NameError`.)

```
color = ''
while color != 'red':
    color = input('guess color please ')
    if color == 'red':
        print('you got it right')
    else:
        print('you are wrong')
```